# unable to put json file in an ordered HTML that looks prettier

Tags: html, json

I am trying to put my contents of JSON files in a prettier HTML format with tables and rows and probably colors too but have no idea how can I do that. Can anyone please assist. Below are two JSON files I am trying to put it in HTML file

'''
{"CorrelationId": "awsnightlyendtoend_zone08_20190828T2319", "ValidationType": "validate_adwactivityfact", "Success": false, "OutputPath": ["s3://zone08-data-validation/awsnightlyendtoend_zone08_20190828T2319/validate_adwactivityfact/requires-replay.csv", "s3://zone08-data-validation/awsnightlyendtoend_zone08_20190828T2319/validate_adwactivityfact/require-investigation.csv"], "ValidationDetail": "Comparison Failed: matched=146455, missing=6, mismatched=0, percent success=99.9918066925666%"}

{"CorrelationId": "awsnightlyendtoend_zone50_20190828T2303", "ValidationType": "validate_adwactivityfact", "Success": false, "OutputPath": ["s3://zone50-data-validation/awsnightlyendtoend_zone50_20190828T2303/validate_adwactivityfact/requires-replay.csv", "s3://zone50-data-validation/awsnightlyendtoend_zone50_20190828T2303/validate_adwactivityfact/require-investigation.csv"], "ValidationDetail": "Comparison Failed: matched=145541, missing=24, mismatched=0, percent success=99.96702504036%"}
'''

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to do it once, you can use an online json to html converter (like this one: http://convertjson.com/json-to-html-table.htm
If not, you'll have to use some javascript to convert parse the json and display as html.
(Probably just [jQuery](https://www.jquery.com) may do the trick)

Comment: Its' an iterating job. So this thing will probably not work. But thanks for the suggestion. might need somewhere in future